# All emails on Google Workspace account marked as spam

Tags: email, gmail, google-workspace, email-spam

I have several emails hosted on Google Workspace with a company domain.  Somehow every email from this domain is being marked as spam for recipients.  This is a small company and is no way engaged in any spam activities.  These are just business email accounts but have somehow been treated as spam to recipients.

The issue seems to span multiple email providers on the recipients and multiple accounts on Google Workspace, which is why I think the entire domain is having this issue.

How can I fix this, the company is suffering as a result?

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious, are the recipients using Google Workspace or another system? If they're using Google Workspace, they can simply click on "Not spam" to ensure the system adds it to the whitelist.